# Sorting nested arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that looks something like this, sorted by city name.
What is the easiest way in PHP to sort this array to display New York on top followed by London and then the rest will be sorted by the City name as they are now.
Have in mind that this is a very long array that I have shortened for this question.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Berlin
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => London
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => New York
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paris
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: are the positions of NY and London always the same or do you have to get those?

Comment: they are not the same, I am getting them yes

Comment: Find key of element you want to be on top, create temporary array containing only element you want to be on top and unset this value from array, then merge temporary array with the original array and use `usort` on sliced array from position 1 (assuming keys always will be numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$arrayCity; //your array
$newYork = null;
$london = null;
// Get London and New York and remove them
foreach ($arrayCity as $key => $item) {
    if ($item[0] == "New York") {
        $newYork = $item;
        unset($arrayCity[$key]);
    } elseif ($item[0] == "London") {
        $london = $item;
        unset($arrayCity[$key]);
    }
    // break if they were found
    if ($newYork && $london) {
        break;
    }
}
// Add them at the top
array_unshift($arrayCity, $newYork, $london);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a ghetto solution:

```
$arrayCityIndex = array(); // Creating an array for sorting the keys while preserving index numbers.
$arrayNYLondonCityIndex = array();

foreach ($originalArray as $index => $cityArray) // Iterating through the original array.
{
    if ($cityArray[0] != 'New York' && $cityArray[0] != 'London') // Adding non NY and non London to array of indexes first.
    {
        $arrayCityIndex[$cityArray[0]] = $index; // Creates a City Name => Index Number hash.
    }
    else if ($cityArray[0] == 'New York' || $cityArray[0] = 'London')
    {
        $arrayNYLondonCityIndex[$cityArray[0]] = $index;
    }
}

ksort($arrayCityIndex); // Sort the index array by the key

$sortedArray = array();

foreach ($arrayNYLondonCityIndex as $cityName => $index) // Iterate through the hash of indexes and for each city in the hash, return the city's array in the original array (using the associated index number), and add it to the sorted array.
{
    $sortedArray[] = $originalArray[$index];
}

foreach ($arrayCityIndex as $cityName => $index)
{
    $sortedArray[] = $originalArray[$index];
}

var_dump($sortedArray);
```

It's quite a hackish way to approach the solution, but I think it should work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the binary search logic to search for London and NewYork, remove and place it in the front.

```
$cityList=<the above array>;
$key="London";
$start=0;
$end=count($cityList);
$mid=($start+$end)/2;
while($end>=$start)
{
if($cityList[$mid][0]==$key)
{
    $keyForLondon=$mid;
    break;
}
elseif(strcmp($cityList[$mid][0],$key)<0)
    $start=$mid+1;
else
    $end=$mid-1;
$mid=($start+$end)/2;
}
$temp=$cityList[$mid];
unset($cityList[$mid]);
array_unshift($temp);
<Similar for New York>
$cityList=array_values(array_filter($cityList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom sort-function :

```
    // Input array
    $cities = array(
            array('Berlin', 1),
            array('London', 2),
            array('New York', 4),
            array('Paris', 5),
            array('Test', 12),
            array('Zzz', 3)
    );

    // Custom sort function
    function customFilter($a, $b)
    {
            static $firstEntries = array('New York', 'London');

            foreach ($firstEntries as $name)
            {
                    if ($a[0] == $name)
                            return -1;
                    if ($b[0] == $name)
                            return 1;
            }

            // Unprioritized : sort by name
            return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }

// Original array order
var_dump($cities);

// Filter and dump of the new array order
usort($cities, 'customFilter');
var_dump($cities);
```

The `$firstEntries` array is customizable and will prioritize the defined names.